# HighChart displaying legend icon along with Y axis

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple Y axis and to differentiate the Y axis I want to display the legend icon just beside Y axis. So is there any way to do this I know we can make the Yaxis itself as the color matching with series but unfortunately that is not needed.

Comment: Where icon should be placed, because you can use icon in the title and set useHTML flag as true.

Comment: The icon should be displayed in place of title. So suppose we have 3 series(s1, s2 and s3) and 2 Y Axis(Y1 and Y2). where s1 and s2 corresponds to Y1 and s3 to that of Y2. So legend icon of S1 and S2 will be displayed in place of title of Y1 and legend icon of s3 will be displayed near  Y2 axis. Hope I am clear....

Comment: Have you any mockup ?

Comment: I am not sure about mockup. but we use PhantomJs for generating high chart.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts is super nice because most text elements will have a `style` element associated with them. This uses CSS to style the text element for you.

So you can make the [`yAxis.title.style`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title.style) [red](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/title-style/) or whatever color you want. This isn't just for titles, you can also make the values of the axis a certain color as well with [`style`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.style) (make them [red](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-style/), or whatever you want).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I want it in different way please see my comment above.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now. In the past, for what you're talking about, I have used a hack. You can use a static positioned html element and place an image on top of the chart to make it look like it is part of the chart.

Comment: ok then How can you differentiate which image is for which series. If you are using some static html.